# How to fix the duplicate word of arraylist in hashmap?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Make a program that can sort words based on their first letter.  Start with a normal loop-till-quit app.  Your data will be stored in "A Map of String to List of Strings".  Each time the user enters a word, look at the first letter and add it to the correct list.  After they quit, print out all of the words for each letter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> MyMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> MyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int input;
    String MyString = null;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Press (1) to enter a word. n/Press (2) to exit.");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            scanner.next();
            System.out.println("Need to press number (1) or (2)");
        }
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter a word:");
            MyString = scanner.next();
        }
        if (MyMap.containsKey(MyString.substring(0, 1))) {
            MyMap.get(MyString.substring(0, 1)).add(MyString);
        }
        if (!MyMap.containsKey(MyString.substring(0, 1))) {
            MyList = new ArrayList<String>();
            MyList.add(MyString);
            MyMap.put(MyString.substring(0, 1), MyList);
        }
        if (input == 2) {
            MyMap.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            });
            break;
        }
    }

    scanner.close();

}
```

My output will print out the duplicate of the last word which I type in.

For example:

Enter a word:
aa
ab
ba
bc
Press (1) to enter a word. Press (2) to exit.
2
a [aa, ab]
b [ba, bc, bc]

Answer (score 0):

You only test if `input` is `1` before assigning a new value to `MyString`, but when `input` is not `1` (e.g. `2`) you continue with the previous value (e.g. `bc` a second time). Change

```
if (input == 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    MyString = scanner.next();
}
```

to add an `else`; like

```
if (input == 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    MyString = scanner.next();
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Also, you should follow Java naming conventions. `MyString` looks like a class name. Instead of an `else`, you could move the following logic up; (I refactored it a bit). Like,

```
if (input == 1) {
    String s = MyString.substring(0, 1);
    if (!MyMap.containsKey(s)) {
        MyMap.put(s, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    MyMap.get(s).add(MyString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the type of your map to fit your needs:

```
Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>>
```

The duplicated values will not be inserted in the set, and you'll keep the insertion order.

```
Map<Character, LinkedHashSet<String>>
```

seems even more accurate, as you only want characters in the key values.